# Non-existence of nontrivial finite group extension of any simply-connected Lie group

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, group-cohomology, algebraic-k-theory

Let $Q$ be a simply-connected compact Lie group. Can one outline the proof (or provide the counter examples if my statement is false) that

> there does not exist any group $G$ (with no topology) with a finite normal subgroup $N$, such that $G/N=Q$, where $N$ is not a direct factor of $G$?

Note that this is always false for $Q$ connected but not simply-connected.

(It is easy to come up with counter examples for connected Lie groups, such as $U(1)/(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})=U(1)$, $Spin(n)/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})=SO(n)$. But those $Q$ are $U(1)$ and $SO(n)$, they are not simply-connected Lie groups.)

I would like to see that such finite group extensions cannot exist for $Q=\mathrm{SU}(N)$ explicitly. Perhaps more generally, one can argue that for $Q$ of type $A_n,B_n,C_n,D_n,E_6,E_7,E_8,F_4,G_2$, the above statement can be proved to be correct(?).

Comment: $G\rightarrow Q$ is a finite covering, use the simple-connectedness of $Q$. The question is not appropriate for this site.

Comment: The question doesn't say if it is assumed that $G$ has a structure of Lie group compatible with that of $Q$ (in which case @abx's comment applies) or if this is just abstract algebra (in which case probably the answer is still affirmative, but if so then seems to require input beyond the theory of compact Lie groups).

Comment: Let $G_0$ be the unit component of $G$. Since $G_0\to Q$ is a connected covering, it is an isomorphism. Hence $G$ is the topological direct product $G_0\times N$. So it's indeed immediate and compactness of $Q$ is unnecessary. (The non-topological version referred by @nfdc23 is indeed less clear but does not seem to be the intention of the question.)

Comment: About the "discrete topology" version suggested by @nfdc23, partial results are in Hurley's 1983 thesis https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/alumni/1983-John-Hurley.pdf. It seems from its introduction (discussing Milnor's conjecture) to be known, at that time, to hold at least when all factors of $G$ are classical. (The vanishing, predicted by Milnor's conjecture, implies in degree 2 that the abstract $H_2$ of a simply connected compact Lie group is $p$-divisible for all $p$.)

Comment: Indeed, thanks everyone for comments, I consider not just $H$ as a Lie group, but $H$ can contain some discrete topology or finite group sectors.

Comment: I changed the tags since the topological tags such as "general topology" were not appropriate, while (non-topological, non-algebraic) central extensions of simple algebraic groups are naturally considered in K-theory.

Comment: It seems you can get a counterexample for any simple Lie type having a nontrivial Dynkin diagram automorphism: $A_\ell$ for $\ell \geq 2$ or $D_\ell$ or $E_6$: here the finite group of outer automorphisms of your group $Q$ has order 2 or 6.    So just form a (non-split) semidirect product.    This should apply in particular for special unitary groups of rank $\geq 2$..

Comment: @JimHumphreys you understand the extension in the wrong sense. The finite subgroup should be normal. Btw it follows from my second comment that the answer is positive in classical groups, so $SU(3)$ will not be a counterexample.

Comment: @wonderich I erased the sentence "it is easy to come up..." you put again because it's redundant with the statement I added just before, that it's trivially false in the non-simply-connected case. Indeed if $Q$ is a connected, not simply connected Lie group, it has a nontrivial finite covering $G$, say with nontrivial finite kernel $N$. Then $G$ being generated by its 1-parameter subgroup, it has no finite quotient (as an abstract group, not only as a topological group), so is not isomorphic to $Q\times N$ as an abstract group.

Comment: @YCor: Quite right.   I must have read the question too quickly.